# Writing a debbuger visualizer for pyCaffe?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, pycaffe, debuggervisualizer

I use caffe under Python in the Visual Studio IDE and I looking forward writing some custom visualization code for debugging purpose, i.e. inspecting caffe layers, in a similar way to the image inspection extension that exists for openCV, for example :

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki/Debugger-Visualizer

First question : can I write the debugger side code in any language (say C#) and later use the extension when coding  python in visual Studio… ?
I guess yes since the build of the visualization extension ends as DLL but I will have to put the DLL in a specific directory and tell Visual Studio to use this DLL

So if I can write the debugger side code in C#, when I derive a class from the class DialogDebuggerVisualizer, the C# code need to know information about the caffe classes (blob for example) to extract the information. How to achive this ? How link the caffe définitions to the C# code ? And the documentation specifies that the object to display should be serializable…

Maybe it will be easier to code the debugger side in C++ since caffe is written in C++ ?
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: _can I write the debugger side code in any language (say C#) and later use the extension when coding python in visual Studio_ In principle, you should be able to use any .NET language, including IronPython and python.net.

Comment: _the documentation specifies that the object to display should be serializable_ -- As an alternative, you could write a serializable "wrapper" class, that contains all the information you want to display. This object will get created on the debuggee side, using the target type of the visualizer, and then get serialized and sent across to the VS side. https://wrightfully.com/debugger-visualizer-for-nonserialized-types

Comment: For a sample of a visualizer for non-managed types, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/SqliteVisualizer), as noted in the [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2017#write-custom-visualizers).